# Printing cells with colored background as cells with white background

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel sheet containing several cells that have a colored background that have to be filled by the user with data.

Is there a way to print the sheet so that those cells are printed with a white background ?

In other words I want those cells to have a colored background only on the screen but not on the printer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there a way to print the sheet so that those cells are printed with a white background?

Two solutions are presented below:

1. Use conditional formatting.
2. Use styles.

---

#### Solution 1 - Use conditional formatting

> If you aren't using conditional formatting for any purpose in a worksheet, you could use it to create your background.
>
> - In a blank area of your workbook, define a cell that contains the value True.
> - Then select your worksheet that you want to have the background color and use a conditional format to define that color.
> - The format can look at the cell you defined, and if it is True, then the color is applied.
> - If the cell is not True, then the color is not applied.
>
> This allows you to turn the background color on or off (for printing) by changing the value of a single cell.

---

#### Solution 2: Use styles

> You could also define styles for use in your worksheet.
>
> - Define a style that has the desired background color, and another that does not.
> - You can then apply the colored style when editing and the non-colored style when preparing to print.

Source [Changing Excel's Background Color](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T006121_Changing_Excels_Background_Color.html)